# "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function" when trying to seperate columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

So I have this dataset

```r
# A tibble: 268 x 1
   `Which of these social media platforms do you have an account in right now?`
   <chr>                                                                       
 1 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat, Reddit, Signal                      
 2 Reddit                                                                      
 3 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat, Reddit, Quora             
 4 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat                                      
 5 Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Snapchat                                       
 6 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat                            
 7 Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Linkedin, Snapchat, Reddit                     
 8 Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat                                               
 9 Linkedin, Reddit                                                            
10 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, TikTok                                        
# ... with 258 more rows
```

and I want to break this into multiple columns with yes and no on each variable like this

```
# A tibble: 268 x 8
      Id Facebook Instagram Reddit Signal Snapchat TikTok Twitter
   <int> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  
 1     1 No       No        No     No     No       No     Yes    
 2     2 Yes      Yes       No     No     Yes      No     Yes    
 3     3 No       Yes       No     Yes    No       Yes    No     
 4     4 No       Yes       No     No     Yes      No     No     
 5     5 No       Yes       No     Yes    Yes      Yes    Yes    
 6     6 No       Yes       No     No     No       No     No     
 7     7 No       No        Yes    Yes    No       Yes    Yes    
 8     8 No       No        Yes    No     No       No     Yes    
 9     9 No       No        Yes    No     Yes      Yes    No     
10    10 No       Yes       Yes    Yes    Yes      No     Yes
```

So I wrote this code to do so

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

Survey %>%
  mutate(Id = row_number(), HasAccount = "Yes") %>%
  unnest_tokens(Network, `Which of these social media platforms do you have an account in right now?`, to_lower = F) %>%
  spread(Network, HasAccount, fill = "No")
```

but I get this error

```
Erreur : Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 268 but must be size 1.
```

```
> dput(head(Survey[1:5]))
structure(list(Horodateur = structure(c(1619171956.596, 1619172695.039, 
1619173104.83, 1619174548.534, 1619174557.538, 1619174735.457
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?` = c("Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"), What_is_your_age_group = c("[18-24[", 
"[10,18[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[25,34["), How_much_time_do_you_spend_on_social_media = c("1-5 hours", 
"1-5 hours", ">10 hours", "5-10 hours", "5-10 hours", "1-5 hours"
), `Which_of_these_social_media_platforms_do_you_have_an_account_in_right_now?` = c("Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat, Reddit, Signal", 
"Reddit", "Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat, Reddit, Quora", 
"Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat", "Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Snapchat", 
"Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT: Edited the question based on @CSJCampbell's answer.
EDIT: Added a snippet of the dataset I'm working with.

Comment: It is working fine for me.  Please specify the `packageVersion('dplyr')`, `packageVersion('tidytext')` and also check if there are any functions that got masked

Comment: @akrun ````> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.6’
> packageVersion('tidytext')
[1] ‘0.3.1’````

Comment: I think this as mentioned in the solution below, your dataset object may be a different name than `df`

Comment: @akrun I fixed and got another error I edited the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument to `mutate` must be a data.frame. You did not name your data.frame `df`, so the function `df` is passed to `mutate`.

```
args(df)
# function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
# NULL
```

EDIT: After your update you added `dput` output of your data. Running your code gives me the error:

```
Survey %>%
    mutate(Id = row_number(), HasAccount = "Yes") %>%
    unnest_tokens(Network, `Which of these social media platforms do you have an account in right now?`, to_lower = F)
# Error in check_input(x) : 
# Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
# vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

Your `dput` has the column named with underscores:

```
colnames(Survey)[5]
# "Which_of_these_social_media_platforms_do_you_have_an_account_in_right_now?"
```

Renaming the column:

```
Survey %>%
    transmute(Id = row_number(), HasAccount = "Yes", 
        Platforms = `Which_of_these_social_media_platforms_do_you_have_an_account_in_right_now?`) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(Network, Platforms) %>% 
    spread(Network, HasAccount, fill = "No")
# # A tibble: 6 x 10
#      Id facebook instagram linkedin quora reddit
#   <int> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr> 
# 1     1 Yes      Yes       No       No    Yes   
# 2     2 No       No        No       No    Yes   
# 3     3 Yes      Yes       Yes      Yes   Yes   
# 4     4 Yes      Yes       No       No    No    
# 5     5 Yes      Yes       No       No    No    
# 6     6 Yes      Yes       Yes      No    No    
# # … with 4 more variables: signal <chr>,
# #   snapchat <chr>, tiktok <chr>, twitter <chr>
```

Comment: yes indeed my dataframe's named Survey, now I get this error ````Erreur : Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 268 but must be size 1.````

Comment: @wageeh after your edit I cannot reproduce your error, the code works for me as you expect on the `Survey` data.frame

Comment: I'm going to reinstall R and Rstudio I think I have packages problem or something.

Comment: @wageeh I don't think it's an installation issue, it looks like the column (length 268) is getting passed to the wrong argument or something. Are you able to create a reproducible example where we can run some code in a clean environment and see the same error? You can use `dput` to output a table snippet.

Comment: I edited the question and added a dput is that what you need?

Comment: @wageeh it looks like your column name has underscores and is not found by `unnest_tokens`

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer to this exact question, but similar enough to the post title that I think it's relevant...)

I ran into a very similar error for a slightly different (but related) reason, namely, I mixed up `ggplot` and pipe (`%>%`) syntax.  I wrote:

```
df %>%                 # <- pipe
   summarize(...) +    # <- NOT a pipe!
   mutate(...)
```

resulting in the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "name"
```

This is, as in the accepted answer, due to `mutate()` not getting a data frame as its first argument.  I'm adding this as an answer rather than a comment to highlight this kind of mistake which can be easy to make when working within the `tidyverse`, and especially when switching between manipulating data and updating plots, but which might not be obvious at first glance.